python regex to get text within a pattern defined
I'm working on writing a parser to extract information from the output given below

i need to get all the three texts which are in between '--'. so i wrote a regular expression as below
import re
def parse_ib_write_bw(mystr):
    output = dict()
    # match = re.search('--+\n(\n|.)*?--+', mystr, re.I)
    match = re.search('--+\n(.*)--+(.*)--+(.*)--+', mystr, re.DOTALL)

    if match:
        print(match.groups(1))
        print(match.groups(2))
        print(match.groups(3))

parse_ib_write_bw(my_str)

My understanding is:
--+\n(.*)--+    -->  This would give the output of the first block  until second  '---' is found

(.*)--+ --> would give the second block until the third '--' is found 

(.*)--+ --> would give the third block until the final'--' is found 

but i get the entire output. where i'm going wrong with my understanding?

You could also split: re.split('(?m)\n?^--+$\n?', mystr)[1:4]

Wow. This works perfect to. need to understand a bit on this pattern. WIll take a days time and come back with specific questions if any.

it just splits at any lines that contain two or more hyphens and optional newlines around. (?m) is a short for re.MULTILINE to make ^ and $ match start/end of line. The [1:4] slices off the first item and will give you the needed three items.

Since . matches a newline in DOTALL mode, the first .* matches all the text between the first and the last line of dashes, while the last line of dashes is matched by the latter --+(.*)--+(.*)--+ where the two .*s match an empty string.
You can instead use ^ in MULTILINE mode to assert that each line of dashes begins at the start of a line and is followed by a newline:
re.search('^--+\n(.*)^--+\n(.*)^--+\n(.*)^--+\n', mystr, re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)

Demo here

Thanks a lot. that works perfect. Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation as well
